# How to avoid importing default symbols when using a module?

Tags: raku

I am going to use [`Hash::Merge`](https://github.com/scriptkitties/p6-Hash-Merge) as an example. Consider:

```
use v6;
use Hash::Merge; # <-- imports all symbols marked with "is export" from Hash::Merge
my %hash1 = a1 => [1, 2, 3], b => "xxx", c => { ca => 1 }, e => 5;
my %hash2 = a1 => [1, 5, 3], b => "yyyy", c => { ca => 5, f => "a" }, d => 4;
my %res = merge-hash(%hash1, %hash2, :no-append-array);
```

Suppose I do not want to pollute my name space when using a module (here `Hash::Merge` is used as an example). I could achive this in Perl 5 by specifying an empty argument list to `use`:

```
use Hash::Merge ();   # <-- No symbols will be imported into the current namespace
```

Then I would call the sub routine `merge-hash` using its fully qualified name:
`Hash::Merge::merge-hash`.

According to [this bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127305) it seems like this is not possible in Perl 6. Is this correct?

Comment: Not sure the bug applies here. You could theoretically change symbol names on the module side by using export magic, but I don't think it can be used in the client side. Problem is all that part is under-documented, so it might... TL;DR you are right, you can't do that. Longer answer: well, maybe, who knows...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To load a module without importing, use `need` instead:

```
need Hash::Merge;
```

In the case of the module in question, it does not declare the things it exports with `our`, which unfortunately means that calling it as:

```
Hash::Merge::merge-hash(...)
```

Will not work, since it's not installed in the package. However, it is still possible to dig the symbol out of the exports manually:

```
need Hash::Merge;
say Hash::Merge::EXPORT::DEFAULT::merge-hash({ a => 1 }, { b => 2 })
```

And, for more convenience, it can be aliased:

```
need Hash::Merge;
my constant &merge-hash = &Hash::Merge::EXPORT::DEFAULT::merge-hash;
say merge-hash({ a => 1 }, { b => 2 });
```

There is a speculated syntax along the lines of `use Hash::Merge :MY<&merge-hash>`, which is not implemented in current Perl 6 versions, but would probably have the same semantics as the `constant` trick shown here.

Comment: cf https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=128090 (I didn't find a replacement issue in rakudo's GH issues queue.)

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to deal with this is to just put the use of the module in a block.

```perl6
{ use Hash::Merge }
```

Since the `{}` defines a scope, nothing escapes it.

You can get it so that something can escape by placing it in a `do` block.

```perl6
do { use Hash::Merge }
```

What you can do then is have it so that the values you care about get stored in the correct places.

```perl6
my &merge-hash = do { use Hash::Merge; &merge-hash }
```

```perl6
my (&merge-hash,&merge-hashes) = do { use Hash::Merge; (&merge-hash, &merge-hashes) }
```

---

Another option is to just place it in as small a scope as possible.

```perl6
my %a = a => 1;
my %b = b => 2;

my %c;
{
  use Hash::Merge;
  %c := merge-hash %a, %b
}
```

or

```perl6
my %c := do {
  use Hash::Merge;
  merge-hash %a, %b
}
```

(The binding operator `:=` was just used because the result of `merge-hash` is already a hash.)